# GAE Indexing (all over again)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

My GAE app has no indexes in the Datastore Indexes tab, it stores only temporary data in the Blob format (never more than 1 meg, that is, only 1 blob entity), but still, it makes about a thousand Index Writing Ops, and the "used" proportion of the datastore keeps growing.

I know there is a possibilty to purge the indexes by using a command line utility Google provides with the SDK, but is there a way to completely avoid indexing the data that should not be indexed at all? Or at least purge them from the app itself?

**UPD:** I use Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very simple solution to this thing: you can tell GAE that a certain property should not be indexed by using JDO annotations:

`@Persistent
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.unindexed", value = "true")
    private Blob b;`

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid to create useless index on properties your app does not need to filter, you could set to False the `indexed` parameter of the `Property` class.

> **indexed**
>
> Whether this property should be included in the built-in and
>   developer-defined indexes. 
>   If False, entities written to the datastore
>   will never be returned by queries that sort or filter on this
>   property, similar to Blob and Text properties.

Documentation [here](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html).

Comment: I am sorry i didn't mention it in the first post, i use java.